# InvalidSyntax: Invalid syntax at line 1

Tags: python

i am reading a file which contains multiple dictionary in following way : -

```
{Attribute_1:Value1,Attribute_2:"Value2",Attribute_3:"Value3",Attribute_4:"Value4",Attribute_5:{created_by:"shivanshu",creation_date:2021-06-10T15:06:41.846-00:00,changeId:"12345"},Attribute_6:"Value6"}
```

I'm trying to read the file to get Attribute_2 from each dictionary using the below code .

```
import ast

with open('file_name.txt','r') as file:
    # reading each record
    for line in file:
        line = line.strip()
        print("Data type before Reconstruction: ",type(line))
        print("line is :",line)
        dict = ast.literal_eval(line)
        print("Data type after Reconsturction: ",type(dict))
        print(dict)
        print(dict[2])
```

But it's throwing below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "code.py", line 13, in <module>
    dict = ast.literal_eval(line)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1

{Attribute_1:Value1,Attribute_2:"Value2",Attribute_3:"Value3",Attribute_4:"Value4",Attribute_5:{created_by:"shivanshu",creation_date:2021-06-10T15:06:41.846-00:00,changeId:"12345"},Attribute_6:"Value6"}

Invalide syntax .
```

Can someone please help me in this case ?

Thanks .

Comment: Because that is invalid literal, string values need to be enclosed inside quotes, or double quotes, but your data does not have that for some key, and values. You need to manually form the dictionary from the string being read from the file.

Comment: @ThePyGuy , it looks so , does there any feasible way to do so , As my filesize is around 3000 dictionary . doing manually doesn't seem to be feasible .

Comment: @Shivanshu — I can see a solution here using regular expressions. But I'm wondering why you have an invalid representation of a dictionary saved to a file in the first place. Can I ask how the dictionary was written to the file, and if there's any possibility of redoing that?

Comment: This is some system Generated output , sadly this is the input format that i got .

Answer (score 0):

Your line is should be looking like a valid dict.

```
{"Attribute_1":"Value1","Attribute_2":"Value2","Attribute_3":"Value3","Attribute_4":"Value4","Attribute_5":{"created_by":"shivanshu","creation_date":"2021-06-10T15:06:41.846-00:00","changeId":"12345"},"Attribute_6":"Value6"}

dict[2] # there is no key "2" in the dictionary.
```

Comment: this is even failing before coming to dict[2] statment .

Comment: yeah...that is the next other error in your code. Modify the line and then fix "dict[2]".